# activeadmin rails 4 understanding how to create custom forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I am new to activeadmin / formtastic and I have having a bit of trouble understanding how things work. I read through the documentation on how to create a form using formtastic but I seem to be still running into issues and I am sure its me not understanding how things work.

I am creating a discussions application very similar to a blog application and the end result is that I would like to create an interface for the administrators to add comments to discussions without having to go into the users interface.

My starting point is the discussions view in the admin section presented by activeadmin. I am attempting to work on the add comment form. According to the instructions, I should be able to add a form using

```
form partial: 'new_admin_comment_form', locals {discussion_comment: DiscussionComment.new}
```

which then I should create this partial in app/views/admin/discussions folder. I have done that and have entered some arbitrary text to make sure the partial renders and it does. But once I start adding code I am not able to get the form to display.

The current code I am working with is:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, discussion_comment] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs, :body %>
    <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

So a few questions I have that I wasn't able to find in the documentation:

1. Where do I create instance variables to be used in my form? I have been setting these in the activeadmin files and that is bothering me.
2. How do I pass params around? I assumed I could do this as normal yet when I try to view them using <%= debug params.inspect %>, it is empty even when I should have at least the id that was in the parent form. Even when using locals: {id: params[:id]}, id is empty in the partial.
3. What are the best ways to debug why my form is not appearing? Am I able to use regular ERB if worse comes to worse?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without a custom form.  If you stick to the active admin DSL you can use its has_many method.  Example here:

http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

Your Discussion model should look like this

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :discussion_comments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :discussion_comments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: I tried to modify the example and got the following errors when:

Comment: The following link shows the current error I get when I added the has_many form:
http://pastebin.com/tpHiz2MC
 
The link below is what I put as my form in the admin/discussion.rb. Based on the example this looks like this is all I should need.

http://pastebin.com/xvnMRaif

If I am understanding how has_many works in the DSL, I am assuming that it is looking at my discussion model to see if I have a has_many :discussion_comments line in there which I do.

http://pastebin.com/zDAm8F4g

It looks pretty straight forward but I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: OK, my issue was related to putting my form in the show block. This is what was causing the error. But interesting enough, I don't get an error but I don't see any form fields for creating a new comment.

Comment: OK, so it looks like I was creating more work for myself. Using the show block removes the ability to add additional forms (it seems). My current admin/discussion.rb file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/jfjgsSkg . The show block displayed but the form didn't. Turns out I didn't need the show block at all since I get the comments form by default. Only reason I used the show block was to render a partial of associated comments. I can't seem to find out how to do that since using render outside of show gives an error and form :partial doesn't display (assuming cause its not a form.)

Comment: OK so that's not right either. The comment section looks like its just internal and has nothing to do with the discussion comments as previously thought. So at this point, I am at a loss as to why the form inputs for a related table does not show and how to render a partial to list those related comments. At this point this is all I have in my admin/discussion.rb http://pastebin.com/qRW2u3JM . I removed the render since there isn't much point to it unless I can get comments to be created in this view using the has_many form.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with that. I guess at the moment its beyond me to figure out. I will have to try again at another point in time when I have time to dig into it and really figure it out.

Comment: the question asks how to create custom forms, not how to use the active admin dsl

Comment: The OP also said he was new to the framework and therefore the idea that this type of suggestion would be helpful is reasonable and certainly not worthy of a downvote.